# Is there a public repository of common formating styles for QGIS? Specifically for Tiger data?

Tags: qgis, style, tiger

I have downloaded the Tiger data for a map I'm working on and wonder if there is somewhere I can download the common formatting styles for these shapes so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.  For example, interstates are blue with the number in an interstate symbol, highways red, water is blue, etc. etc.

Obviously I can manually go in and set that for everything, but I wonder if that has already been done somewhere so I don't have to spend the hours reinventing what I'm sure has been done countless times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find much but someone has already made a sample style layer for common line styles in TIGER shapefiles such as freeways/highways etc. You can download it from [here](http://www.johnhickok.com/tutorial/Index.html) by selecting the **QGIS Styles** hyperlink on the left-hand side.

It includes several files such as a sample shapefile and style files of the following:

- PLSS_Sections.qml - A QGIS style file for symbolizing and labelling polygons representing Sections of the United States Public Lands Survey System.
- StreetMap.qml - Another QGIS style file for symbolizing streets and street names.
- StreetNamesImagery.qml - A third style file is used for labelling TIGER street names on top of imagery.

There is a list [*MAF/TIGER Feature Class Code Definitions*](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/mtfcc.html) which was developed by the US Census Bureau to classify and describe geographic objects or features.

But alternatively, you could **Save** your style layer and load it for each of your desired layers instead of having to constantly 're-invent' them:

[image: Save style]

Comment: Most welcome buddy! Hope it was helpful.